# local isometry between $x(u_{0},v_{0})= (\sinh u\cos v,\sinh u \sin v, v)$ and a helicoid

Tags: differential-geometry

Define:
\begin{equation}
x(u_{0},v_{0})= (\sinh u\cos v,\sinh u \sin v, v)
\end{equation}
I want to show that there is a local isometry between $x(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and a helicoid:
\begin{equation}
y(u_{0},v_{0})= (u\cos v,u \sin v, v)
\end{equation}
So I have to find a differentiable function $\phi$ that maintains lengths of curves between $x(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $y(\mathbb{R}^2)$.
Should I take $\phi: (u\cos v,u \sin v, v) \rightarrow (\sinh u\cos v,\sinh u \sin v, v)$? I don't think so because it seems that $\phi$ don't give the same of length of curves.

Comment: The image of $x$ _is_ a helicoid. Is one of your surfaces a catenoid, by chance?

Comment: I thought $x$ is a catenoid, $y$ is helicoid.

Comment: Since $\sinh$ is a diffeomorphism (a.k.a. a smooth function with positive derivative), the image of $x$ consists of lines orthogonal to the third axis, rotating at uniform speed, and the identity map (send $x(u, v)$ to $y(\sinh u, v)$) is an isometry. Perhaps you want $$x(u, v) = (\cosh u\cos v, \cosh u \sin v, u),$$the catenoid obtained by revolving the graph of $\cosh$ about the third axis? If that's the case, it's straightforward to show that your $x$ and this $x$ have the same $E$, $F$, and $G$. :)

Comment: But should the $E,F$ and $G$ of the $x$ and $y$ (in my question) then not be the same?

Comment: Not necessarily: Most reparametrizations are not isometries, and the map $x(u, v) \mapsto y(u, v)$ is not an isometry.